# moderação agressiva: é o que queremos?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade

Estava lendo perguntas aleatórias no site quando me deparei com esta situação. (Retirei o nome dos usuários para não expor ninguém)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode ser que eu esteja sendo muito sensível, mas se no início da minha colaboração no site eu tivesse sido recebido desta forma, isso teria me desencorajado bastante para continuar respondendo.

Acredito que a própria votação das perguntas irá deixar a melhor resposta lá na frente. Também tem aquele ponto de que uma resposta incompleta é melhor do que nenhuma resposta.

E também será que responder *sem ter certeza* * é errado?

*O que é ter certeza?

Enfim, acho que podemos ser mais cordiais na moderação.

Comment: O comentário foi meu, não vejo problema algum em mostrar. E não vi problema na forma de tratar, não acho que fui grosso com o OP.

Comment: Um dos comentários, independente da sua intenção @diegofm, poderia ser interpretado como grosseiro, e inclusive foi sinalizado. Eu excluí.

Comment: Responder sem ter certeza de uma maneira geral é errado. Pode haver exceções, tem que analisar cada caso. Mas respostas devem ser corretas. Eu acho que comentários indicando o problema, ou tentando chegar em um ponto de congruência são melhores que os negativos, que pode ser dados também. A discussão ficou um pouco sem sentido sem os nomes. Tive que ir na pergunta e ver o contexto, e claro, vi os nomes. Pode ser eu que não alivio, mas não vi agressividade alguma ali (no máximo um caso que dá margem para interpretação). Apaguei os comentários que nada ajudavam a resposta prosperar.

Comment: Eu estou esperando pra ver se melhora ou não para negativar, porque a resposta é ruim. Já houve discussões antes sobre negativar ou criticar o problema e não se chegou a uma conclusão porque cada um se doí mais de um jeito ou de outro. Uns ficam bravos por receberem negativos, outros por receberem críticas. O que eu acho que não pode é deixar conteúdo ruim ou errado sem atitudes. Aí devolvo a pergunta, qual sua sugestão nesse caso? E o que a sua sugestão torna o site melhor? Alias, está melhorando e só ocorreu depois de haver intervenção. Sem ela ficaria ruim e ninguém ganharia nada.

Comment: Pessoal reclama de negativos sem justificativas. Quando se justifica reclama também. O jeito é fingir q nem viu mesmo.

Comment: Não vejo problemas em expor, o pessoal participativo é bem maduro aqui e sabe debater

Comment: @bfavaretto qual dos comentários? Estou muito tranquilo de que não faltei com respeito em nenhum deles.

Comment: Eu sou a favor do comentário, mas acho que precisamos tomar cuidado com a linguagem. Eu acho, mesmo, que fazer um questionamento do tipo "se vc não tem certeza, como respondeu?" pode afastar usuários do site, e não é isso que queremos. É possível falar de outras formas, por exemplo: "a sua resposta está incompleta, ela poderia ser melhorada se você deixasse claro se existe diferença entre bla e blabla e se você falasse sobre não sei o que lá." Não é fingir que não viu, mas se atentar a forma que está dizendo. Nem todo mundo tem a mesma percepção de um comentário, principalmente pela internet.

Comment: Acho bom haver atenção de todos para não sermos rudes com ninguém. Acho bom também haver critica (construtiva claro) a apontar respostas que surgem sem se ter a certeza do problema. Eu próprio tenho de me conter, e uma vez ou outra caí no erro de responder sem ter certeza do que era pedido.

Comment: Também não estou dizendo que estou certo. Foi a minha percepção.Se fosse eu, preferiria ter sido tratado de outra forma.

Comment: Estou começando agora no stack e fui eu quem postei a resposta. Achei que o comentário do @diegofm não acrescentou em nada, poderia ter sugerido uma melhora, como já fizeram outros usuários. Sou aberta a críticas e acho válida e concordo com o Daniel que é frustrante e desanimador continuar respondendo perguntas depois dessa.

Comment: @Taisbevalle mas vc mesma comentou que não tinha certeza de um dos tópicos que respondeu. Não entendi como meu questionamento foi ofensivo.

Comment: Só um detalhe, não vi mal algum na maioria dos comentários, o que eu vi foram indagações sobre uma confusão de entendimento que o AP teve, o problema é que as pessoas não presumem a boa intenção, ou seja mande o link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice ..., eu sempre escrevo de maneira a dizer, entenda como uma critica construtiva em um primeiro comentário mais duro, se ele tornar a repetir e só questiono mesmo que soe mal, afinal tem que se fazer e saber aceitar ajuda.

Comment: @Taisbevalle entendo e concordo com seu ultimo comentário (o que você apagou), mas o problema é que as pessoas tem que presumir boa intenção, de ambos lados, claro que tem comentários que obviamente são desrespeitosos, mas não me parece nenhum dos casos, no máximo uma troca de farpas, isso porque o AP não está entendendo o que foi solicitado por quem foi ajuda-lo.

Comment: Creio que é bom tomarmos cuidado com o que escrevemos,para não ofender, e ao mesmo tempo, como usuários,não achar que tudo que se escreve é uma ofensa.Cada pessoa tem uma personalidade diferente e um jeito de falar diferente. Se todo comentário crítico for considerado uma ofensa ( problema que já foi discutido sobre deixar o comentário quando dá  downvote, por exemplo), então é melhor ninguém  mais comentar nada, já que estará sempre sujeito a interpretação negativa do outro.Eu já citei que evito comentar negativos em certas questões, principalmente quando são sei que o usuário vai achar ruim.

Comment: @diegofm O que eu excluí foi o *se você não tinha certeza, como respondeu?*

Comment: @DanielFalbel "Nem todo mundo tem a mesma percepção de um comentário, principalmente pela internet" E isso também não seria o caso das pessoas aprenderem lidar com comentários que elas não gostam? Não seria o caso de tentar ver comentários incômodos também com cabeça aberta? Tudo tem dois lados. É óbvio que existem coisas pesadas demais, mas muitas vezes a pessoa fica procurando problema no que leu. A internet não é lugar para esperar a melhor expressão da palavra. É difícil passar uma ideia completa em poucas palavras, ninguém sabe da entonação que a pessoa está usando, da expressão facial.

Comment: Eu vejo ser muito comum alguém escrever algo na boa intenção e ser interpretado por quem lê como má intenção. Aí eu pergunto: O problema é de quem escreveu ou de quem leu? Eu acho que as pessoas precisam aprender entender a internet, saber que ela é um meio de comunicação limitado. Acho que todo mundo precisa aprender lidar com comentários questionadores, críticos, até mesmo secos. Se a pessoa não fizer isso vai passar mal em todos sites. Só ressalto a diferença de algo mais forte que pode ser bem intencionado de algo que realmente desrespeita alguém. Existe uma linha tênue.

Comment: @diegofm Já está claro que sua intenção não era ofender, mas não só a Taisbevalle como outros usuários (eu incluso) acharam seu tom agressivo. Acho inevitável que isso ocorra no SOpt, pelos motivos que outros já comentaram aqui (internet, falta de contexto comunicacional etc). Mas principalmente acho muito saudável quando a questão vem pro meta e os envolvidos debatem civilizadamente, como está acontecendo aqui. Neste caso específico, cada lado pode ceder um pouco, e bola pra frente.

Comment: @bfavaretto foi uma pergunta baseada num outro comentário da AP. O questionamento, ao menos da minha parte, não foi pra menosprezar a AP.

Comment: @bigown O problema é de quem escreveu e de quem leu. É uma troca social como qualquer outra. Só que pessoalmente não só há outros recursos para transmitir a mensagem, como tendemos a ser mais cuidadosos. Na internet, especialmente em comentários, infelizmente, as pessoas são muito pouco cuidadosas. Os dois lados precisam aprender a lidar melhor com esse tipo de situação.

Comment: @diegofm Eu sei que não, isso já ficou claro. Mas pra quem olha de fora (e pelo jeito para a própria AP) parecia um bombardeio. Era uma questão de *tom*.

Comment: @bfavaretto É verdade, mas já tive situações aonde fui bem educado mas o usuário era cabeçudo e depois de uns 5 comentários meus ele ainda não tinha entendido as dicas (em todos comentários fui educado), então ele começou a ser bem estupido, eu nem respondi mais. Para concluir, sempre faço um primeiro comentário educado e os demais se o AP não entender eu faço direto, obviamente não estou falando para ser grosso, apenas direto e até com um leve puxão de orelha :p ... Agora se desde o primeiro comentário eu for "direto" então eu discordaria :)

Comment: @bigown das tags ninguém fala, mas há uma polémica vem toda a gente :P

Comment: @JorgeB. melhor comentário até agora, pena que não dá pra estrelar :D E eu ando enrolado esses dias pra pegar firme nelas...

Answer (score 15):

Considerando o conteúdo da pergunta e dos comentários que se seguem, bem como a resposta do Daniel Falbel, eis aqui a minha opinião:

1. Se a pergunta não tiver resposta e não for uma pergunta recém-postada, postar uma resposta incompleta ou parcial é melhor do que não postar resposta nenhuma. Por vezes isso já é o suficiente para ajudar o OP a pelo menos chegar mais perto da solução do problema. Se você puder completar a resposta depois, edite-a.
2. Se uma das respostas dadas está incompleta, superficial, incorreta, etc e você pode postar uma resposta melhor, então vá em frente e poste uma resposta melhor.
3. Embora cada um possa usar o upvote ou o downvote como quiser, espera-se que as pessoas os utilizem com bom senso. Se alguém postou uma resposta incompleta ou superficial, mas que ainda assim ajudou o OP de alguma forma, então não acho que mereça downvote. Para mim, o downvote é algo só para casos realmente sérios. Mais abaixo eu explico o que considero motivo para downvote.
4. Se você acha que uma determinada resposta está incompleta, mas não tem como postar uma resposta melhor, então fique a vontade para postar comentários se tiver algo a contribuir.
5. Comentários apontando problemas são bons, mas tome cuidado para não partir para ataques pessoais ou apelar a emoções mais fortes. **O nível ideal de emoção que um comentário desse tipo deve ter é o mesmo nível de emoção que o compilador demonstra quando aponta um erro de sintaxe no seu código.** Em caso de comentários com ataques pessoais ou emoções mais exaltadas, não suba o tom das críticas/comentários/réplicas/etc, apenas sinalize.
6. Comentários com piadinhas ou com uma dose de sarcasmo, desde que seja leve e não ataque ninguém, acredito que estão ok. No entanto, aprecie com moderação.
7. Quase todo mundo que está aqui, está aqui para ajudar uns aos outros, inclusive com críticas negativas (porém construtivas). Lembre-se que ninguém ou quase ninguém aqui conhece você pessoalmente ou realmente se importa de verdade com o seu problema, então não faz sentido que alguém aqui queira te atacar com a intenção de te prejudicar e também não faz sentido com que você saia atacando os outros e tente prejudicá-los. Isso daqui não é comunidade sobre política, religião ou futebol, então por favor, mantenha-se calmo.
8. Você nunca vai agradar todo mundo. Embora críticas construtivas sejam boas, cedo ou tarde vai aparecer um ou outro para postar um comentário com uma crítica totalmente infundada ou até mesmo dar um ou outro downvote não merecido. Nesses casos, apenas mantenha-se calmo, mantenha o bom nível do debate e não esquente a cabeça.
9. Se você postou uma resposta que realmente era muito ruim, tomou um monte de comentários criticando e levou uns downvotes, então apenas delete a resposta e deixe pra lá. Ninguém vai ficar te aporrinhando no futuro por causa disso. Se isso aconteceu, provavelmente é porque você estava errado mesmo, mas depois de deletar a resposta, é praticamente como se você nunca a tivesse postado.

Eu poderia dar uns exemplos concretos de comportamentos como esses que citei acima, mas não vou postar links para não ficar parecendo que quero me aproveitar do meta para promover ou atacar respostas que nada tem a ver com esta pergunta. Portanto apenas irei descrevê-los de forma genérica:

- Há uns dias atrás, eu vi uma pergunta com uma resposta que considerei bem fraca e superficial. Não dei downvote nessa resposta porque na minha visão ela era um esforço válido para ajudar o OP e não tinha nenhum grave problema que pudesse produzir o efeito oposto (desorientar, atrapalhar ou confundir o OP ou os demais). Entretanto, considerei que uma resposta bem melhor era necessária e que eu poderia produzi-la. Inicialmente a minha resposta era pra lá de incompleta, mas o OP logo postou um comentário dizendo que estava ficando muito legal apesar disso. Editei ela várias vezes durante o dia para que melhorasse e no final tenho uma resposta excelente que recebeu um monte de upvotes e foi aceita.
- Outro dia, vi o Bacco fazendo algo parecido. Ele postou uma resposta que inicialmente era fraquinha em uma pergunta, o que não é algo típico por parte dele. Entretanto, ele foi editando a resposta e logo ela se tornou em uma excelente resposta. Eu pretendia postar uma resposta também e estava começando a tentar escrevê-la, mas ao ver o Bacco editando a resposta dele, desisti de postar a minha porque a dele estava muito melhor do que eu faria.
- Ainda no começo do período de beta deste site, postei uma resposta um tanto polêmica que um determinado usuário reagiu mal e de forma um tanto exaltada (não era o OP). Entretanto, quando eu pensava em responder um comentário dele, os comentários dele já tinham sumido.
- Já postei algumas críticas como comentários em perguntas e respostas que não foram lá muito bem recebidas pelos respectivos autores. Na maioria dos casos, quando o debate desanda, apenas deixo-os falando sozinhos ou deixo que outros usuários participem e fico olhando de longe. Considero que a minha ajuda em relatar algum tipo de problema já foi dada, e se a pessoa em questão quiser teimar, ignorar ou desprezar, aí já não é problema meu.

E por fim, eu raramente dou downvote, tanto em perguntas quanto em respostas. Eu particularmente reservo os downvotes apenas para os casos mais graves que não podem ser resolvidos de outra forma (tal como sinalizar para excluir, fechar a pergunta ou postar um comentário crítico). Normalmente os reservo para:

- Respostas que ensinam más-práticas de programação.
- Respostas que têm problemas e erros óbvios, grosseiros e ridículos, que demonstram que o seu autor (a) nem mesmo leu a pergunta ou (b) tem extremo desleixo com o que postou ou (c) não tem a menor ideia sobre o que está falando e não tem a mínima competência nem mesmo para tentar chutar ou adivinhar a resposta.
- Respostas que desorientam, desinformam, atrapalham ou confundem os usuários do site (em especial o OP).
- Respostas que não apenas estão erradas, mas são respostas realmente idiotas no qual o autor teima, insiste e faz questão de ser idiota.
- Perguntas ou respostas onde o autor claramente é mal-intencionado. Não basta ser ingênuo, leigo ou mal-informado, tem que ser um babaca mesmo.
- Perguntas onde o autor insiste em fazer as coisas erradas e do jeito errado e teima em desobedecer ou ignorar orientações dadas em comentários.

Enfim, o meu limiar particular para dar downvote é bem alto, e por isso que menos de 3% dos meus votos são negativos. Além disso, só dou voto a favor se eu achar que o conteúdo for minimamente bom, não saio dando upvote de graça a torto e a direito, e portanto se tivesse como computar os casos de no-vote junto com os downvotes e upvotes, a minha taxa de downvotes seria algo talvez em torno de 0,5% a 1%.

Nos casos onde alguém posta como resposta algo que não é resposta, eu sinalizo e deixo que a fila de análises a exclua automaticamente (se algum moderador não o fizer antes) e dependendo do caso sinalizo pedindo para um moderador converter em comentário.

Dar uma resposta incompleta, porém correta até onde está para mim não é motivo de downvote. E mesmo se a resposta for incompleta e errada sem que o autor informe ou se dê conta disso, se eu julgar que postar um comentário seria melhor do que dar voto contra, é isso que farei. E mesmo no caso de uma resposta errada ou incompleta, se a resposta acabar por ajudar de alguma forma significativa, pode até levar upvote.

E novamente, esta é apenas a minha opinião pessoal.

Comment: +1 gostei da tua opinião.

Comment: Ótimo. Concordo com tudo, só acho que usando os seus critérios de *down*, era para negativar muito mais. Provavelmente não vê tudo o que tem de errado por aí. O problema relatado no debate aqui foi essencialmente um comentário "se você não tinha certeza, como respondeu?", que pode ser interpretado por quem leu como algo mal intencionado. Ou pode ser interpretado como uma pergunta simples e direta, esperando uma justificativa. Não estou dizendo que não poderia ser feito de forma melhor. Mas ele encaixa no item 5, é um "comentário de compilador".

Comment: Eu nem sei se o problema foi tão grande quanto esse debate aqui faz parecer. É o que eu já falei antes e posso tentar explicar melhor agora. Se fosse um compilador que tivesse dito ninguém acharia ruim, como foi uma pessoa que disse, passou ser um problema. Tanto que tem gente que se irrita com mensagens do sistema, quando sabem que é automático a pessoa se acalma (ou seja é um problema psicológico do ser humano mais que um problema do texto em si). Por isso que um debate saudável, mesmo que duro é algo bom, só não pode baixar o nível, ir para caminhos que não levam para lugar algum.

Comment: @bigown Quanto aos downvotes, sei que há coisas terríveis por aí, mais nas perguntas do que nas respostas. No caso das perguntas, as que têm os piores problemas são fechadas e acabam sendo deletadas automaticamente depois de uns dias, e por isso nem precisa esquentar a cabeça muito com elas. Além disso, quando esbarro em questões que não entendo do assunto tratado, ou não tenho tempo suficiente para analisar com calma (o que é comum), eu apenas deixo pra lá e acabo não votando em nada.

Answer (score 10):

Vou deixar o meu último comentário como resposta:

> Eu sou a favor do comentário, mas acho que precisamos tomar cuidado com a linguagem. Eu acho, mesmo, que fazer um questionamento do tipo "se vc não tem certeza, como respondeu?" pode afastar usuários do site, e não é isso que queremos. É possível falar de outras formas, por exemplo: "a sua resposta está incompleta, ela poderia ser melhorada se você deixasse claro se existe diferença entre bla e blabla e se você falasse sobre não sei o que lá." Não é fingir que não viu, mas se atentar a forma que está dizendo. Nem todo mundo tem a mesma percepção de um comentário, principalmente pela internet.

Claro que, como muitos levantaram, é importante (se não for um dever) que todos tentem interpretar os comentários e críticas como boas intenções, e não como um desrespeito ou ataque. Mas também, acredito que é um dever de todos que forem comentar que leiam, releiam e pensem se agiriam daquela forma em uma conversa com um amigo/colega. Enfim, que tentem minimizar as más interpretações.

Answer (score 10):

Só postei como resposta, pois não cabia nos comentários, e como o assunto foi trazido para o meta, deixou de ser
um problema só entre os dois usuários da postagem original e virou coletivo.

Vejo três problemas essencialmente:

### O tom do comentário

Creio que houve um descuido com o uso das palavras. Realmente poderia ter sido posto de outra forma.

Digo isso como quem fazia isso muito mais, no começo do site. Por acreditar na boa intenção de todos, sempre escrevi
sendo "seco", imaginando que o leitor iria pressupor que se eu estou investindo meu tempo para escrever, é por achar
que algo pode ser melhorado, e que eu acredito na capacidade da pessoa em melhorar. Quando eu considero que não há
muito onde melhorar, eu nem comento.

Só que... nem todas as pessoas são iguais. Então, tenho feito um exercício, que ainda está longe do ideal, mas espero
que melhore com o tempo. Muitas vezes, tenho vontade de escrever no imperativo "voce não pode ..." "Não dá para ..."
e muitas outras coisas que eu realmente tenho certeza, mas que nem todo mundo recebe bem. Assim, tenho dado preferência
para um "*Talvez* fosse melhor", ou "*Seria legal se* você pudesse..." e outros termos "amaciando" a conversa.

A intenção é que a pessoa esteja aberta a ler, pois meu objetivo na verdade é compartilhar algo, e não disputar com o
colega de site. Se é assim, melhor tomar cuidado para não ter sua intenção confundida, então um treino em melhorar a
parte "social" ajuda. Da mesma forma que eu tenho tentado, talvez seja um exercício para o @diegofm em posts futuros
(se bem que eu tenho a impressão que eu nem precisaria ter dito isto depois da polêmica toda).

### A postagem em questão

Antes de mais nada, o que motivou a discussão foi a postagem. As razões foram mais do que explicadas, e realmente me
parece que o post tinha problemas que justificavam alguma ação por parte dos leitores. Mas não muda o fato de se ter
maneiras e maneiras para lidar com o assunto, que é o ítem anterior.

Isto posto, o que mais regula o site são os votos, e os comentários acessórios vão ficar sempre na discussão entre
"comentar com medo de represália", "não comentar e deixar o autor do post sem um precioso feedback para melhorar",
e também o "comentar com cuidado para não ofender nem o autor nem o leitor", o que é algo muito delicado quando se
trata de uma imensidão de pessoas.

Solução? A comunidade votar sempre com atenção no conteúdo, não economizar votos quando souber do assunto (sejam a
favor ou contra) e ao comentar, pensar no exercício do cuidado com as palavras, nem que seja por excesso de zelo.

### Trazer para o meta a questão

Por mais que o @Daniel tenha razão em estranhar o comentário feito (e eu realmente acredito que o caminho é maior cuidado
com as palavras), provavelmente bastaria um comentário pro @diegofm na própria postagem questionando.

Já que trouxe pro Meta, o que eu acho válido em princípio, não gostei da idéia do screenshot "anonimizado". Não combinou
legal com o discurso de preservar qualquer parte, pois eu que frequento um pouco o site, imediatamente sabia de que postagem
se tratava, e duvido um pouco ter sido o único.

Lendo este post do meta me deu uma impressão ruim, de "certeza absoluta" da intenção ofensiva do autor do comentário".
Eu sugeriria mais cuidado com esses absolutos, pois passou a ser um terceiro envolvido que já julgou, condenou e executou por
conta própra um suposto desentendimento entre duas outras pessoas completamente diferentes. Sem esse cuidado, é como jogar um
bocado de gasolina na fogueira enquanto os bombeiros não chegam.
E que fique claro que pode ter sido só um problema de interpretação meu. Mas foi essa a impressão passada.

Seria muito mais legal um cuidado com as palavras, algo como "Não sei qual foi a intenção do autor, mas *a mim soou como*
um comentário ofensivo" etc, de preferência chamando as pessoas envolvidas para a conversa no meta, OU, anonimizar de uma vez,
e explicar o ocorrido de outra maneira. Eu acho sempre melhor chamar os envolvidos, mas isso vai de cada um. O que não dá é
ficar no meio de campo.

### Resumo

Acho que todo mundo tem que olhar para o próprio umbigo antes de mais nada, julgar os outros é muito fácil. Claro que, uma vez
tendo olhado com cuidado, podemos partir para o zelo do coletivo. Mas preferencialmente nessa ordem.

Que o exercício da melhoria valha para todos os envolvidos, direta ou indiretamente. Comentaristas, autores, nós aqui que
chegamos depois, e todos que vierem em seguida.

Sejamos cada vez mais legais, e vamos presumir boa intenção e avaliar tudo com cuidado. Antes de responder, antes de comentar,
antes de postar no meta, antes de responder no meta, e assim por diante.

A antagonia ao post principal é mero contraponto expondo como eu vi. Não pretendo "ter razão" nem "estar errado", é irrelevante para o objetivo. O ponto mais importante pra mim é deixar claro o relativismo da coisa, que o que agrada ou desagrada cada um de nós pode não ser a mesma coisa ou atitude. E, tendo vontade, é mais fácil controlarmos o nosso papel do que o do outro, afinal de contas.

Comment: Concordo, exceto pelo seu terceiro ponto. Ao meu ver essa postagem cabe perfeitamente no meta. Eu tentei desconectá-la do post específico (sem sucesso), mas mesmo que fosse sobre o próprio post ela caberia. Concordo que meu post julga a tonalidade do comentário, mas ele serve pra julgar mesmo. Eu não gostei e não gostaria se tivesse acontecido comigo. No entanto, lendo e relendo o meu comentário não consigo encontrar uma frase que soe agressiva (claro, entramos em um loop). Por fim, no resumo você fala que julgar os outros é muito fácil. E isso é verdade, não errado

Comment: Estar aberto a críticas, como o @diegofm estava, e como eu estou é o que mais importa.

Comment: Está perfeito. Isso mostra como é problemático buscar as relações perfeitas. Até podemos buscá-las, mas exigir que tudo funcione perfeito não dá. Sempre haverão escorregões. E esse debate mostra como é possível ser o mais bem intencionado possível e ter alguém que acha que foi mal intencionado. Não estou entrando no mérito do comentário debatido ou desse debate aqui. Mas para ser justo, ambos podem ter causado um mal estar. E aí as respostas, os comentários também podem. E isso não tem fim.É melhor procurar ver a boa intenção, até mesmo quando se tem quase certeza que não é o caso.

Comment: Vi algo interessante em um debate sobre as redes sociais: "democracia é menos sobre o direito de falar e mais sobre a capacidade das pessoas ouvirem". É sobre aceitar que o outro diga, mesmo discordando radicalmente, mantendo o nível do debate, sem ofender, mesmo que o outro lado "mereça". Um comentário ruim pode fazer uma pessoa se afastar do site, um debate acusatório pode fazer uma pessoa não colaborar mais. Viu como é difícil? A solução passa por diminuir a hipersensibilização atual. A outra "solução" é as pessoas pararem de se falar. Devemos fazer ambos: falar melhor, ouvir melhor.

Comment: @bigown não sei se concordo totalmente com esse negócio de tentar ver a boa intenção, até quando não é o caso. A boa intenção é necessária em qualquer relação (pelo menos a não-má intenção). Discordar radicalmente e não se ofender. Sim! Hipersensibilizar? Você tá me chamando de hipersensível? ;)

Comment: @DanielFalbel se for olhar bem, lendo sua pergunta(como o Bacco bem clarificou na resposta) eu poderia interpretar que estaria afirmando que fui mal intencionado e não fui cordial baseado na forma que você interpretou meu comentário, eu percebi isso assim que li na primeira vez mas preferi ver pelo lado de que a sua intenção em trazer a discussão para o meta era discutir sobre como agir nos comentários sem causar interpretações prejudiciais. Acredito que seja isso que o bigown quis dizer.

Comment: Pra mim, se todo mundo entender que cada um pode ver onde melhorar o seu próprio ato, tá tudo encaminhado para a solução. Só quis tirar o foco do "onde o outro" pode melhorar e jogar de volta em nós mesmos. A antagonia ao post principal é mero contraponto expondo como eu vi. Não pretendo "ter razão" nem "estar errado", é irrelevante para o objetivo. O ponto mais importante pra mim é deixar claro o relativismo da coisa, que o que agrada ou desagrada cada um de nós pode não ser a mesma coisa ou atitude. E, tendo vontade, é mais fácil controlarmos o nosso papel do que o do outro, afinal.

Comment: @diegofm eu entendi! O meu comentário foi sobre a hipersensibilidade foi uma brincadeira :) Tudo é relativo mesmo! Estamos falando de como outras pessoas interpretam o que a gente fala. Achei ótima a discussão que tivemos aqui!!

Comment: Eu acho que o resultado da discussão foi positivo. E ver a forma saudável que a discussão rolou aqui, me deixa com ainda mais vontade e orgulhoso de participar da comunidade.

Comment: É extremamente raro ter exageros de comportamento aqui. Não somos o Facebook. Tem pequenos deslizes. Ou seja, tem quebra-espinha, mas não tem limão no olho :D #SaudadesDoTelecatchClássico (quem não tem referência não vai entender a piada) Temos que respeitar as diferenças. Tem coisas que são obviamente prejudiciais, outras dependem de julgamento moral, aí entra-se em um terreno perigoso.