# Tolerância dos moderadores

Tags: debate, fechamento, moderação

Muito recentemente eu fiz a seguinte pergunta: [Qual é a maneira mais correta para armazenar arquivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/229856/qual-%C3%A9-a-maneira-mais-correta-para-armazenar-arquivos?noredirect=1#comment470692_229856)

Pouco tempo depois um moderador fechou a pergunta e a sinalizou como duplicada, apontando para duas outras questões. Eu olhei as questões anteriores e nenhuma delas sanava minha dúvida, voltei e fiz uma pequena modificação explicando porque as perguntas não se encaixavam no que eu estava tentando dizer.

Logo depois outro usuário comentou que não estava conseguindo responder, e até mesmo tentou me ajudar ali pelos comentários mesmo.

Entendo a importância de todos os moderadores do site, que realmente lutam para manter um ambiente decente aqui no SOpt, mas minha crítica aqui é a seguinte, é justo uma pergunta ser fechada por que só **você** achou que a pergunta não estava "correta"?

Entendo que talvez eu tenha pecado na hora de expor a minha questão, mas logo em seguida alguém comentou tentando me ajudar e essa pessoa realmente tinha entendido o que eu havia tentado dizer.

A questão é que eu acho que deveria ter uma tolerância um pouquinho maior do pessoal de alto escalão, e esperar para ver se a comunidade não consegue se entender, e só aí então intervir de alguma forma.

OBS: Até o momento a questão segue fechada, mesmo eu e outras pessoas entendendo que ela não é duplicada, mas infelizmente não temos a pontuação para abri-la

Comment: Além de duplicata, na forma atual, ela é **baseada em opiniões**. Se você tem dúvidas específicas, faça novas publicações com perguntas específicas.

Comment: "baseada em opiniões", eu acho que não, afinal como o próprio comentário de quem tentou me ajudar disse, existe um estudo que mostra perca de desempenho de acordo com o tamanho do arquivo e etc
E oq eu gostaria de ter ouvido era vantagens e desvantagens de cada uma das situações, isso se encaixa como __baseada em opiniões__?

Comment: Sim, isso se encaixa em baseada em opiniões. Inclusive, jovem, o próprio comentário de quem tentou te ajudar diz: "_A resposta é **depende de cada caso** (...)_". Isso abre brecha pras respostas principalmente baseadas em opiniões e isso é uma coisa que não queremos. Na publicação você pergunta: "_É ideal que (...)?_" e "_É mais viável (...)?_", isso é depender de caso, especificação, etc. - Informações estas que não são passadas na pergunta. Se você quer saber qual a vantagem/desvantagem de cada abordagem faça uma pergunta dizendo isso, na forma atual, abre muita brecha pra respostas ruins.

Comment: Quanto ao questionamento: "*é justo uma pergunta ser fechada por que só você achou que a pergunta não estava "correta"*", sim, é. Essa é a função do moderador. Sem o voto deles, são necessários 5 para fechar uma pergunta.

Comment: Sem contar que a pergunta foi respondida nela mesma: "*Como os arquivos podem se tornar bem grandes, acho que isso pode ser um problema na hora de armazenar diretamente no banco*"

Comment: Hmmm, aproveitando para resolver mais algumas dúvidas, no caso de eu fazer uma questão duplicada, eu devo remover a pergunta?

Comment: @JoséHenriqueLuckmann Pode manter no site, armazenamento custa quase nada pra SO (e mesmo que custasse, não é nosso problema). Na maioria das vezes duplicatas são muito úteis justamente porque levam até a pergunta principal usando um título diferente ou até mesmo um texto completamente diferente.

Comment: Relacionada: [Pergunta fechada corretamente ou uso excessivo de poder?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6064/pergunta-fechada-corretamente-ou-uso-excessivo-de-poder), [Moderação agressiva: é o que queremos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5348/modera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-agressiva-%C3%A9-o-que-queremos)

Answer (score 13):

O fato de ter apenas a pessoa que pergunta e a pessoa que quer responder algo que já foi respondido não quer dizer que essas pessoas também têm razão. O debate sempre pode ser feito, se houve equívoco pode ser resolvido.

O que eu tenho para dizer especificamente é que por um lapso peguei um dos *links* equivocadamente, agora coloquei o certo.

Eu li e reli e acho que é duplicata, se acha que não é, precisaria argumentar, mostrar melhor porque não é, o que está lá indica que é, só faltou ser com as mesmas palavras, mas a mesma resposta que for dada aí na nova pergunta é a que já foi respondida em outras perguntas. Tanto que o comentário postado fala basicamente o que já foi respondido nas outras duas perguntas. Se o autor do comentário quiser dá até para responder lá se ele considerar que acrescenta algo novo na pergunta já feita antriormente.

É compreensível que todo mundo que posta algo no site queira que fique aberto, mas se formos tolerantes não pode ser em bases individuais, aí o motivo de fechar por duplicata deve ser descartado, o que é um debate válido também.

## Edição.

O autor reconheceu que é duplicata.

Comment: Eu acho que o fechamento com aquelas perguntas foi válido. Se for para guardar arquivos no banco acho que a primeira pergunta linkada é leitura essencial.

Comment: Perfeito, até não acho que o link que você linkou estava errado, ele realmente agregou para o meu conhecimento no assunto. Só que eu precisava de mais argumentos para poder decidir qual recurso usar para a minha solução

Comment: @JoséHenriqueLuckmann Se precisa de mais argumentos de uma pergunta já feita você pode usar o sistema de recompensa em uma das perguntas já existentes pedindo atualização do que foi perguntado.

Answer (score 13):

Eu sempre considero o voto vinculante (seja de moderadores ou "medalhistas" de ouro) uma das maiores responsabilidades do site. A ideia dele é principalmente "desburocratizar" casos óbvios, não decidir o que acontece com a maioria dos casos.

Pra cada moderador/medalhista existem mil outras pessoas capacitadas para fazer a mesma avaliação e chegarem à conclusão que julgarem necessária. O fechamento existe para ser efetuado por 5 pessoas diferentes. Isso dá peso e honestidade à decisão, que foi tomada comunitariamente. O voto vinculante existe apenas para não sobrecarregar quem realiza esse trabalho.

Acho que as perguntas são similares o suficiente para justificar o fechamento mas, considerando os riscos inerentes à decisão unilateral, *particularmente* eu teria deferido ao resto da comunidade.

O AP precisava de uma solução para o caso específico dele e *nem sempre* a resposta, genérica ou similar, já existente vai dar cabo na dúvida. Em casos assim eu preferiria um comentário do tipo: "*Essa resposta [link] te atende? Por que não?*"

Dá tanto trabalho quanto fechar a pergunta, e evita tomar decisões desnecessárias. Além de fazer o AP pensar melhor sobre o seu problema... Se a outra pergunta resolver, está resolvido; Se não resolver, ele vai ter uma ideia muito melhor de qual a diferença entre sua pergunta e as outras. Mas agora com poder suficiente para mudar o rumo da pergunta. Coisa que não acontece com tanta facilidade pós-fechamento.

Quanto à supostamente ser "baseada em opiniões", não podia discordar mais. O AP apresenta um problema, duas alternativas cabíveis, e faz a pergunta "*existem casos em que posso armazenar [áudio] no banco?*"

Me parece bem claro, e perfeitamente respondível. Assim como a pergunta similar sobre imagens. Acho que não se pode cair na armadilha de que ter "melhor" no título é um teste razoável para decidir se algo é ou não baseado em opiniões.

Comment: Qual versão da pergunta você leu? Foi antes do bigown corrigir o link para a duplicata errada? Concordo que seja respondível, mas me parece muito claramente uma duplicata.

Comment: @bfavaretto Tinha lido a versão atual, mas minha opinião se mantém sobre a original, também. A edição é apenas um parágrafo que cita ter lido uma das perguntas marcadas como duplicada. Como eu disse, eu concordo sobre as duplicatas, só acho que a decisão poderia ter sido deferida à comunidade, ou pelo menos abordada de outra maneira, para gerar menos desentendimento.

Comment: Entendi Gabe. Eu nesses casos costumo deixar comentário perguntando se os links resolvem, mas faço isso porque acho que as mensagens do sistema em perguntas fechadas não são tão simpáticas. Talvez seja melhor atuarmos aí, afinal é redundante ter de re-explicar o que a mensagem de fechamento poderia resolver sozinha.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu acho uma excelente empreitada. Eu vou anunciar mais revisores para o Transifex (semana que vem, acredito) e vamos ter uma boa oportunidade de dar uma olhada com carinho nesses textos mais fedorentos.

Comment: @Gabe uhuuuuuuuuu!!

Answer (score 11):

Vou tentar ser o mais curto possível.

O fato de o usuário que fechou a pergunta ser moderador nesse caso é coincidência. Quando você ganha uma medalha de ouro em uma tag, você ganha o poder de fechar qualquer outra pergunta daquela tag como duplicata. Não precisa ser moderador pra isso.

Se eu tivesse a mesma medalha, teria fechado do mesmo jeito, com exatamente as mesmas perguntas linkadas.

---

Eu vi a sua edição no seu post:

> A pergunta [Como modelar uma estrutura de dados em árvore usando um banco de dados relacional?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2425/1658) cobre bem o assunto, mas para mim ainda não ficou muito claro essa questão do tamanho dos arquivos, e se eles de alguma forma podem afetar a performance do meu banco.

A pergunta original não parecia pedir informações nesse sentido. Se você tem essa dúvida, você pode verificar essa pergunta (que por mim pode ser **adicionada** na lista de perguntas que já cobrem os assuntos da sua):

[O que é mais rápido, acessar dados em arquivo ou banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45423/o-que-%C3%A9-mais-r%C3%A1pido-acessar-dados-em-arquivo-ou-banco-de-dados)

Comment: Ele *linkou* isso porque eu tinha usado essa como duplicata e não tinha nada com o assunto, eu só peguei o *link* errado., se ñ tivesse ocorrido acho que ele nem teria postado isso. Na verdade sei lá porque ele disse que cobre bem o assunto porque nem chega perto do assunto :)

Answer (score 11):

Em relação à pergunta:

> é justo uma pergunta ser fechada por que só você achou que a pergunta não estava "correta"?

Sim, moderadores e utilizadores que tenham medalha de ouro na tag têm o direito de o fazerem se acharem que é necessário.

Isto não quer dizer que a pergunta fique fechada para sempre. Nem quer dizer que não haja mais comunicação ou ajuda por parte de quem fechou, ou da comunidade. Como [o Renan referiu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6285/129) *"O fato de o usuário que fechou a pergunta ser moderador nesse caso é coincidência"*.

Gostava de comentar o titulo da pergunta *"Tolerância dos moderadores"*. Como já disse neste caso é irrelevante ser moderador ou não, mas sim um utilizador com muita experiência e com ferramentas para o fazer. De notar que este utilizador (bigown) está no top 1 ou 2 das tags na pergunta. E recordo que contudo a ação de fechar é reversível: com argumentação sobre o porquê não ser duplicada, e por vontade da comunidade, hoje ou daqui a 3 meses.

Na parte que toca à parte de moderador nós damos do nosso tempo livre ao site. Isso quer dizer que tentamos fazer o melhor possivel de maneira eficaz. A nossa ajuda mantém o site mais limpo, mais organizado. Como somos humanos podemos fazer erros, e caso eles aconteçam existem comentários na pergunta para isso, e/ou a comunidade pode votar para mudar a ação. Já ouve casos destes com o bigown, gabe, comigo, etc... e vai sempre haver.

O que é importante reter é que: há boa vontade, experiência e ferramentas poderosas por parte de utilizadores mais experientes. Tudo o que gerar problemas resolve-se por diálogo partindo do pressuposto anterior: que há boa vontade.

Comment: Concordo com você, e peço desculpas se de alguma forma o título pareceu uma crítica aos moderadores, minha opinião é bem oposta disso, admiro muito o tempo que vocês dedicam ao site e valorizo muito o serviço que vocês prestam ao site.

Comment: No fim das contas teve pequenos equívocos de ambos os lados e isso acabou resultando neste debate, mas já foi tudo esclarecido

Comment: @JoséHenriqueLuckmann otimo. E com o tempo vamos percebendo que somos uma comunidade de pessoas que se ajudam, ensinam e aprendem. Alguns até se encontram no bar :) Eu é que estou para aqui sozinho perdido na Suécia e ninguém me vem cá ver :)