# Fechamento sumário de perguntas

Tags: debate, perguntas, fechamento

Não sei se já existe algo aqui que fale sobre isto, mas algumas vezes algumas perguntas (até boas às vezes) são fechadas de forma sumária, seja por um moderador ou por alguém que possui medalha de ouro da tag (<s>exceto</s> quando for duplicata).

Gostaria de saber quais são os critérios para isso. É apenas uma prerrogativa baseada em julgamento subjetivo? Uma vez que a pergunta não é submetida a voto para fechamento e é fechada sumariamente. Gostaria de entender esses critérios.

### EDIT

Já vi moderador fechando sumariamente algumas perguntas que achei até boas, mas outras esdrúxulas foram submetidas à votação, inclusive algumas com o voto do próprio moderador(?). Por que a "esdrúxula" não foi sumariamente fechada também?

O SOpt destaca que "*o SOpt é moderado por você*", ou seja, esse "você" são todos os usuários que podem votar, aprovar ou rejeitar, alguma coisa de acordo com o voto. Por isso me surgiu a curiosidade em conhecer os critérios de se fechar uma pergunta "na lata", popularmente falando.

Comment: Normalmente é usado um critério objetivo para fechamento de perguntas através do martelo. Existem 10 características de perguntas boas, e 10 de perguntas ruins, que são levadas em consideração nesses casos (o @Renan já postou aqui no meta em uma resposta). Obviamente moderadores são humanos, então pode haver uma má interpretação da pergunta (sem saber as perguntas em questão não tem como afirmar), mas na minha vivência esses erros são raros. O moderador também pode "achar" que a pergunta deve ser fechada, mas não tem certeza, por isso não a martela diretamente e deixa a cargo da comunidade

Comment: Ou eu achava que era do @Renan, estou com dificuldade de achar a resposta que trata disso

Comment: Já vi perguntas sendo fechadas com todo o mérito (se pudesse, até apagava do banco de dados do site :p), mas já vi algumas sendo fechadas quando eu estava há 1 hora formulando uma resposta, simplesmente porque o moderador _achou_ que estava "fora do escopo" ou sei lá oq. Claro que o moderador pode achar uma coisa de acordo com seu entendimento, que pode ser falho ou não, mas confesso que dá um sentimento de arbitrariedade, sem chances de defesa, "fechou e pronto". É frustrante, pra não dizer outra palavra.

Comment: Fez bem abrir a questão. É sempre bom tentar esclarecer os assuntos. No meu ponto de vista, sempre que visse um caso desses deveria abrir uma pergunta no meta para esclarecer o assunto. Moderadores ou medalhas de ouro tem mesmo esses "poderes" e, como diz o outros, quanto maior o poder maior a responsabilidade... O meta serve para isso mesmo, esclarecer as nossas dúvidas e resolver esse tipo de "conflitos"...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu vi que você me mencionou mas eu não recebi notificação, provavelmente porque tem outros usuários com o mesmo nome que eu.

Comment: @Renan na verdade por você ainda não estar envolvido no post. Enfim, eu jurava que você (e não outro Renan) tinha escrito uma resposta no meta falando dos pontos que indicam quando a pergunta era no tópico ou não, mas não a encontrei

Comment: Pronto, acho que era essa a resposta que eu estava atrás: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6496/64969

Comment: Eu não entendi bem, sua pergunta diz que os golden badge podem fechar perguntas sem levar pra votação? Isso só é possível em duplicatas, não?

Comment: @LINQ Imagino que os golden badge possam fechar uma pergunta, não? Se não for isso, desconsidere essa parte na pergunta porque eu também não entendo muito disso ainda. Estou aprendendo aos poucos.

Comment: @dvd Só no caso de duplicatas, acabei de conferir.

Comment: @LINQ Verdade. Estou lendo aqui tb alguns tópicos. A gente só aprende se ir atrás e perguntar rs, mesmo que ganhe 300 downsvotes rs... é o preço que se paga para obter a informação rs

Comment: Sobre os critérios de fechamento por moderadores, geralmente é bem objetivo, só quando tá muito na cara. Você sempre pode abrir uma pergunta no meta com a tag `pergunta-específica` e trazer para debate o fechamento específico, geralmente isso traz resultados. Pode também votar pra reabrir, isso leva pra fila e a pergunta pode ser reaberta no final das contas. Você também pode mencionar o moderador nos comentários de uma pergunta fechada por ele (quem fecha a pergunta é notificado) e perguntar o motivo do fechamento e vocês podem conversar sobre isso. [+]

Comment: [+] Eu uso o site há um bom tempo e tenho certeza que nenhum dos moderadores vai se negar a conversar com você sobre o fechamento, teve alguns casos beeem específicos que eu sabia do que se tratava uma pergunta muito pouco clara e pedi para o moderador reabrí-la para que eu pudesse responder e depois editá-la para deixar mais claro pra todo mundo. Todo caso é um caso diferente, mas nenhuma decisão de fechamento é definitiva, isso sempre pode ser mudado.

Comment: @dvd Sobre o comentário dos _downvotes_: é que aqui no meta segue-se um padrão diferente do site principal no que tange os votos. Aqui, na grande maioria das vezes, um downvote significa que o votador não está de acordo com o que diz na publicação. Obviamente que sua publicação é mais um questionamento do que uma proposta, mas eu considerei os downvotes como sendo algo como: "não concordo que hajam fechamentos tão ruins assim". BTW, desculpe pela má escrita, dormi muito pouco e estou cansado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse assunto já foi discutido à exaustão no Stack Overflow em inglês, no metão e aqui. Sou antissocial demais para usar os chats de cada um mas imagino que deve ter sido muito discutido neles também.

Então vou fazer um apanhado de respostas anteriores sobre isso.

- Moderadores também são usuários. Se eles têm mais de três mil pontos ou uma medalha de ouro, eles podem usar seus poderes de usuário normal para resolver coisas, sem precisar do diamante.

https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6285/1658

- As vezes uma publicação é simplesmente horrível e precisa ser muito melhorada antes de poder fazer parte do site. No caso abaixo caso um moderador fechou a pergunta duas vezes usando o diamante, o que levou algumas pessoas a achar que fosse abuso de autoridade. Porém se você abrir o histórico de edição da pergunta, você vai ver coisas que é melhor nem serem vistas. O fato de que na segunda votação de fechamento um usuário não moderador participou, que a pergunta tem seis votos negativos e que a comunidade precisou comentar ao infinito até poder ajudar o OP falam volumes.

https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6075/1658

- Sobre critérios de fechamento e bom uso ou mau uso dos poderes relacionados: quem fecha ou mantém abertas publicações ruins é penalizado também. Com grandes poderes vem auditorias.

https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1279/1658

- E finalmente, sobre os critérios para fechar ou manter abertas perguntas, que são objetivos o suficiente para todas as nossas necessidades. Eu os mencionei nesta resposta:

https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6496/1658

<sub><sub>E sim, eu sei que eu pareço narcisista apenas colando links para respostas minhas. É porque eu sou narcisista mesmo.</sub></sub>

---

Mais uma coisa. Falar sobre um caso abstrato não ajuda muito na discussão. Se formos julgar o mérito da coisa em cima de uma situação hipotética, estaremos discutindo o sexo dos anjos. O ideal é ter algumas publicações de exemplo para que possamos analisar e chegar a uma conclusão, como foi o caso de todas as perguntas relacionadas aos links nesta resposta.

Comment: Legal, vou dar uma olhada nas postagens. Mas não são casos abstratos, são concretos e acontecem muitas vezes. Não fui atrás de um exemplo porque achei por bem não expor, e também porque não tenho interesse em fustigar esse ou aquele caso. A pergunta foi apenas mesmo para esclarecer esses critérios de fechamento.

Comment: @dvd a discussão é abstrata até surgir o primeiro exemplo. Quando tivermos um link para uma pergunta eu aceito chamar de concreto.

Comment: Bom, sabemos muito bem que essas coisas ocorrem, logo pra mim são concretas, porque as vejo o tempo todo. rs... Mas acho que buscar um exemplo fugiria do tópico, uma vez que a pergunta não aponta para um caso específico, mas no geral.

Comment: @dvd eu discordo, nunca vi até hoje um caso de fechamento abusivo. Em todas as vezes que discordei de um fechamento, fosse por consenso de voto, martelo de ouro ou moderação, eu fui atrás dos motivos. Acho que fiz isso mais de quarenta vezes desde que entrei no site. Em nenhum caso vi abuso, e em todos os casos nos quais as perguntas foram editadas para se adequar ao site, os fechamentos foram revertidos.

Comment: Eu também nunca vi "abusivo". Eu quis dizer "sumário".

Answer (score 8):

A resposta do Renan já está muito boa, mas vou tentar responder objetivamente:

> Gostaria de saber quais são os critérios para isso. É apenas uma prerrogativa baseada em julgamento subjetivo?

O Renan já mostrou alguns pontos. Os critérios são essencialmente objetivos, cada um dos 8 motivos com seus critérios. A avaliação é subjetiva, sempre foi e sempre será, um humano não consegue ser 100% objetivo.

Eu queria fazer uma postagem mostrando como fechar em cada caso, até porque para cada um tem um critério, mas a ação da comunidade está tão dispersa que nem deu vontade. Como a pergunta trata todos os motivos como uma coisa só e não tem um contexto, me parece que é caso de ser ampla demais.

Mas os critérios são os mesmos se a pergunta é fechada com um voto ou muitos, então a pergunta parece fazer pouco sentido também.

> Uma vez que a pergunta não é submetida a voto para fechamento e é fechada sumariamente. Gostaria de entender esses critérios.

Toda pergunta é submetida a voto. Em alguns casos basta 1 voto. Em alguns precisa 5. Nenhum precisa da maioria dos usuários do site, ou mesmo os cerca de 200 usuários que podem votar para fechar.

Toda reabertura é submetida a voto. Pode ser 1 de um moderador diamante, pode ser 5 de usuários moderadores.

Todas pessoas que podem votar receberam este privilégio porque a comunidade deu. Por isso as pessoas deveriam pensar bem quando votam em alguma coisa, ... em tudo na vida. Alguns ganham o privilégio porque fizeram boas postagens, em alguns casos boas respostas em uma *tag*, e há quem ganhou por ter votos em eleição onde quase toda comunidade pode votar. Então essas pessoas passam ter seus votos com maior peso.

5 pessoas podem votar e estar errado. 200 podem votar e estar errado. Quem é que define isto? Moderadores eleitos supostamente devem fazer isto.

Democracia é o povo governando através de representantes. Moderadores eleitos ou privilegiados são representantes. Então todos estão moderando. Na verdade todos podem sinalizar para fechar. Em nenhum lugar está escrito que só a maioria da comunidade é que decide algo. Pelo contrário, os poderes foram dados para "fechamento sumário" porque isto é útil.

Eu até tenho tido uma visão um pouco diferente de como as coisas deveriam se seguir, mas toda ferramenta precisaria ser reformulada. Acho que a forma atual não está atendendo bem o interesse da maioria, quem pergunta, quem responde, quem fica apenas no *lurking*, quem modera, etc. Eu proporia mudanças se tivesse alguma chance de implementação.

> Já vi moderador fechando sumariamente algumas perguntas que achei até boas, mas outras esdrúxulas foram submetidas à votação, inclusive algumas com o voto do próprio moderador(?). Por que a "esdrúxula" não foi sumariamente fechada também?

Um moderador não é obrigado a analisar tudo, ver tudo, tomar ação em tudo. O que não houve ação de um moderador só significa isso mesmo, não significa que ele aprovou aquilo.

Me parece haver um desbalanço na premissa toda, inclusive porque o texto está um pouco estranho. Parece ser apenas um incômodo por ter alguma pergunta fechada que queria responder.

> Bom, sabemos muito bem que essas coisas ocorrem, logo pra mim são concretas, porque as vejo o tempo todo. rs... Mas acho que buscar um exemplo fugiria do tópico, uma vez que a pergunta não aponta para um caso específico, mas no geral.

De fato não tem nada concreto e não dá para avaliar se houve algum engano, portanto acabou ficando apenas um *rant*. O fato de achar que algo tão abstrato ser concreto já indica que há uma dissonância do conceito, o que pode indicar dissonância objetiva na avaliação. Vez ou outra temos usuários que aparecem com uma visão de mundo toda própria, que é um direito ter, mas não pode ser estendida a todos.

## Conclusão

Pra falar a verdade estou cansando um pouco dessas discussões porque em geral é sobre um interesse específico e não o bem da comunidade.

A pergunta parece ser até fora de escopo, mesmo no meta, pelos [itens 3 ou 4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Não tem como responder isso objetivamente. Não que o assunto não tenha mérito, mas a pergunta é ruim. Casos concretos ficam mais fáceis de avaliar, abstratos precisam ser muito bem propostos, o que não acho que tenha ocorrido.

E "a culpa é do Sérgio Moro". :P

Comment: Vou ter que discordar da sua colocação: "_Pra falar a verdade estou cansando um pouco dessas discussões porque em geral é sobre um interesse específico e não o bem da comunidade._"... vejo muito pelo contrário. A pergunta pode parecer querer atender a um interesse específico, mas como o tópico fica aberto para quem quiser ler, acaba se estendendo para toda a comunidade de forma a esclarecer a quem possa, e vejo isto como algo positivo a todos. Realmente cansa discutir coisas, mas se não chamar para a discussão, fica complicado de saber algumas coisas.[continua]

Comment: Se eu fosse trazer cada caso na pergunta, não caberia de tantos. Por isso eu perguntei de uma forma genérica. Lógico que cada caso é um caso, mas imagino que os critérios não são muitos, eu só queria saber quais são. Mas as respostas já foram suficientes para resolver a dúvida. Novamente agradeço.

Comment: Discutir algo que crie uma evolução, que resolva um problema é uma coisa, ficar discutindo o sexo dos anjos<sup>citation needed</sup> é outra.

Comment: Ok! Vc tem todo direito de ver dessa forma. Abs!

Comment: «Pra falar a verdade estou cansando um pouco dessas discussões porque em geral é sobre um interesse específico e não o bem da comunidade.» Concordo com o dvd neste ponto... De resto concordo com tudo.

Comment: @JorgeB. foi eu que disse isso e é um sentimento meu, não é para alguém concordar ou discordar.

Comment: @Maniero eu estava a dizer que concordo com a visão dele, que vê pelo contrário. Apesar de eu entender o teu cansaço, aconteceu-me o mesmo quando estava mais ativo que agora... Uma desligada faz maravilhas ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. e é um pouco o que estou fazendo, aproveitando que a comunidade tem estado no mesmo barco.