# É permitido perguntar sobre lógica?

Tags: debate

Eu estava 'zanzando' pelo Stackoverflow, e a maioria das dúvidas de iniciantes, eram referentes a lógica. Como sempre, aqueles que querem ajudar pedem código, porém, se eles parassem realmente para ler a questão, deixava bem claro que era de lógica. Tenho a impressão que alguns usuários existe só para falar: "CADE CÓDIGO?" ou "PERGUNTA CONFUSA"

Enfim, voltando ao assunto, é permitido perguntar sobre lógica? Pois uma dúvida bem influente na vida do programador é " Como caral*** farei isso? ", principalmente dos iniciantes. E somente a experiência ajuda nisso. Pelo menos do meu ponto de vista.

Comment: olha essa pergunta, apenas exemplificando o que o @bfavaretto disse
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239450/como-identificar-n%C3%BAmeros-capicua-com-5-d%C3%ADgitos

a pergunta tras apenas logica independente de linguagem, tem uma resposta matematica muito boa

Comment: Não confunda problema de lógica com perguntas mal-elaboradas ou confusas, escrever ao invés de falar geralmente é mais difícil, por isso tenha em mente que possivelmente muitos comentários foram por outros problemas que você ainda não enxerga, o que é necessário experiencia no site.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pode ler meu comentário na resposta abaixo  ? Podemos discutir um pouco melhor isso?

Comment: Pergunta direta e sem código que foi até relativamente aceita (mas que não são conceituais): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216528/64969; https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/246817/64969; https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/246085/64969; https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242007/64969; https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237830/64969; https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232142/64969

Answer (score 13):

Sim, é permitido. O importante é a pergunta não sair do assunto do site e ser bem explicada – com código ou não –, de maneira que os outros consigam responder sem precisar chutar o que a pessoa está fazendo. O Victor Stafusa deu vários exemplos mais concretos desse tipo de problema na resposta dele.

Comment: Eu entendo isso, mas, um iniciante na programação tem muitas dúvidas, raramente vai saber se expressar com termos técnicos ou coisas do tipo. O que fazer com relação a isso? Por quê é fato que, "nenhuma dúvida é estúpida" ( como diria um professor meu ), e do meu ponto de vista os usuários são meio 'agressivos' quando não entendem a pergunta ou algo do tipo..

Comment: @LTafarelo sobre *"agressividade"*: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5348/3635

Comment: Sim, eu entendo que tem formas de denúncia etc... O que não entendo é por que os usuários  se sentem tão focados em "A PERGUNTA TÁ ERRADA" em vez de tentar entender o problema, ou até mesmo SUGERIR uma solução... Talvez apenas um "norte" seja suficiente para a pessoa que fez a pergunta, não?

** Quando digo 'agressivos', não digo no sentido literal da coisa, se não, com certeza denunciaria!

Comment: @LTafarelo o link não fala sobre denuncia, e acho que você não esta entendendo o que estou tentando te passar, o problema não é se a pergunta é sobre lógica e ponto, o problema é que pergunta geralmente possuem outros problemas que só quem tem experiencia os nota, claro que existem exceções, aonde quem comentou exagerou mesmo, então o link que citei acima é sobre isso, sobre comportamento e não "como denunciar", afinal de contas nenhuma das situações discutidas aqui é digna de denuncia, só estamos discutindo sobre ser mais receptivo e o link acima creio que fala disto.

Comment: Na verdade ninguém espera que novatos saibam usar termos técnicos. O que eles precisam fazer – e é uma competência útil na maioria das profissões – é se expressar com clareza, dar o contexto que a pergunta precisa para ser respondida. Tudo bem se a pessoa não fizer isso de cara, aí entram os comentários para a comunidade ajudar a pessoa a fornecer as informações necessárias (repito, não necessariamente código).

Comment: Outra coisa importante é que, embora um dos objetivos do site seja sim ajudar o usuário específico que postou a pergunta, sempre procuramos gerar conteúdos que sirvam pra mais gente. Nessa linha, "dar um norte" para quem perguntou muitas vezes não basta. @LTafarelo

Comment: @LTafarelo, eu sou um dos defensores de dar um norte, mas acontece que a paciência tem limites... Não por conta de um ou outro conteúdo ruim, mas devido a enchurada ruim que as vezes acontece. E também tem outro ponto que é o ônus da responsabilidade: quem pergunta quer ser ajudado, portanto ele deveria facilitar ao máximo o entendimento de quem pode vir a candidatar a responder. Não assuma que, por querer ajudar, somos obrigados a ler nas entrelinhas para poder ajudar. Se algo não ficou evidante e ofuscantemente óbvio, vou perguntar ou dar a sinalização de fechamento adequada

Comment: Exemplo de coisas que tentamos salvar, mas que não garanto termos paciência para conseguir: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251135/64969

Answer (score 13):

Os principais problemas de perguntas de iniciantes que acabam recebendo comentários do tipo *"CADE CÓDIGO?"* ou *"PERGUNTA CONFUSA"* por parte de mim e de muitos outros usuários é porque:

- Depois de ler e reler a pergunta várias vezes, não consigo entender o que raios que o usuário está perguntando.
- O usuário faz uma pergunta tão vaga, genérica e superficial que a resposta pode ser praticamente qualquer coisa.
- O usuário fala que está com um problema na função X porque ela recebe uma String Y lida do arquivo e este quando é processado no XPTO dá um `SbrubblesException`. Mas ele não posta o código de nada disso e todos ficam sem saber o que X, ou Y, ou XPTO.
- O usuário posta um trecho de código ao invés de um código inteiro. Esse trecho usa umas trocentas variáveis, classes e etc que estão definidas sabe-se lá onde. Por vezes, o erro está fora do código que ele postou.
- O usuário faz uma pergunta extremamente abrangente do tipo "*Preciso de um sistema de cadastro de produtos, como posso fazer isso?*"
- O usuário posta um código confuso, enorme, complicado, sem explicação nenhuma de nada e diz apenas o seguinte: "*deu erro*". Quando vejo isso fico tentando imaginar que tipo de erro seria esse.
- O usuário quer saber qual é a lógica para resolver um problema que ele não sabe direito o que é e que parece ser muito esquisito e incomum, tal como "*de que forma posso ter uma variável dinâmica que muda de tipo dentro de uma string tridimensional?*" Isso sempre é um caso de [**problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

Enfim, essas perguntas são quase impossíveis de se responder, e é por isso que recebem esses tipos de comentários, votos de fechamento e votos negativos. Por vezes, alguém tem coragem em tentar postar uma resposta, e quase sempre esse acaba sendo um esforço em vão.

Veja também o [**manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/132).

Comment: Concordei em muitos pontos seus, dei risada na maioria deles, da forma que você escreveu! rs, porém, descordei de dois:

- O usuário faz uma pergunta tão vaga, genérica e superficial que a resposta pode ser praticamente qualquer coisa. -

Bom, pelo fato de ser um iniciante, e o usuário conseguir enxergar 'muitas' formas de responder, por que não responder?? Isso ajudaria e muito, ou até mesmo, ajudaria a explicar a questão. Algo como " Não, não é isso que eu queria saber" sendo assim dando mais detalhes.

Comment: - O usuário faz uma pergunta extremamente abrangente do tipo "Preciso de um sistema de cadastro de produtos, como posso fazer isso". -  Foi uma pergunta muito parecida com essa que eu cheguei aqui. Por que essa resposta não é válida? Esse mês eu estava treinando PHP e pra isso, fazer um sistema de LOGIN. Não tinha a mínima idéia de como fazer isso. Tanto por lógica, quanto sintaxe. Talvez uma resposta de poucas linhas pudesse me ajudar. Por exemplo:
- Tente usar SESSÃO, puxando os dados de uma tabela via SELECT! - Isso com certeza me ajudaria, pois eu teria um 'norte' a ser guiado.

Comment: @LTafarelo As respostas podem ser muitas, contanto que sejam complementares, ou diferentes maneiras de resolver o mesmo problema. Mas a pergunta precisa ser uma só ;) Quando a pergunta é muito vaga ou genérica, ela aceita várias respostas porque pode ser interpretada de muitas maneiras. Nesses casos, preferimos esclarecer do que se trata antes de responder. Às vezes, a pergunta é fechada como ampla demais, e pode ser reaberta se os esclarecimentos vierem.

Comment: "Tente usar SESSÃO, puxando os dados de uma tabela via SELECT!" – definitivamente esse não é o tipo de resposta que queremos. Cabe como comentário, ou no chat @LTafarelo

Comment: Em geral quando a pessoa não consegue formular a pergunta não é que não sabe programação, mas sim tem dificuldades de organizar o próprio pensamento e/ou falta uma base de conhecimento muito anterior à necessária para programar. A pessoa não sabe cortar cebola e quer fazer alta gastronomia, aí não dá certo. Ainda assim a pessoa pode fazer um esforço extra para conseguir o que quer. Mas se a cebola não estiver cortada não vai sair nada.

Comment: @LTafarelo Porque uma resposta do tipo "*Preciso de um sistema de cadastro de produtos, como posso fazer isso?*" continua sendo uma pergunta extremamente difícil de se responder pois o usuário não informa detalhadamente os requisitos. Qual é o banco de dados? Qual framework vai ser usado? Como vai ser modelado? Empresas? Distribuídores? Clientes? Endereço de entrega? Pagamentos? Alterações de preço? Descontos? Nota fiscal? Estoque? Tem aplicativo para celular? É algo tão abrangente que não dá nem para começar a responder.

Comment: "*O usuário faz uma pergunta tão vaga, genérica e superficial*" - tipo, "*quero aprender a programar com PHP, o que faço?*" - Como você responderia isso?